# Too many apps; not enough space on my iPod

Tags: applications, ios, ipod-touch, backup

I have a new PC. I have never used auto sync because I have more data than space on my iPod and I swap songs, movies, photos, and apps back and forth. My new PC now has all my music and photos on it in the Windows folders as well as all the songs in my iTunes library now. I have backed up the iPod through iTunes. I have done the transfer purchases thing, but only 48 of my apps are on my PC and my iPod right now because my old computer died and, as I said, my iPod is small.

Some of my apps are for scrapbooking and are over 100 MB and have cost a fair bit of money with all the add-ons and in-app purchases I've made. My songs will be ok. My photos will be ok. But what about my apps? I am terrified I won't have access to all my apps after I upgrade. Or maybe I'll only have the 48. I cannot use sync because obviously I am a control freak; I mean, obviously the new PC is an issue and the amount of storage space on the iPod and need to swap is an issue and WAY too confusing and time-consuming to have to use the checkmark method. I have to do it manually.

I was hoping to put all the songs and apps in the Cloud once I upgraded and purchase the $25 non-iTunes songs storage thingy so I can swap on the go until I go and get a bigger iPod, lol. But: **will my apps be gone** after the upgrade? Can I not go to iTunes and just reinstall the apps on my iPod when I want them like I have been doing? Will I have to buy them all over again?

My head is very fuzzy, so if this is not making sense, please tell me. I **know** someone out there knows the answer to this and likes to help techno-duds like me.

Answer (score 3):

iCloud can be used to back up your device, but it's not a repository for Apps not in use. However, once you've purchased an app you can redownload it from the iTunes store, free of charge, as long as the app is still available.

You will lose the configuration files and any data files that wasn't saved out to an external source. (This would be the same for any app removed from the device.

To download a purchased app:

1. Open the *App Store* app on your device.
2. Tap the *Updates* tab in the lower right hand corner
3. Tap the *Purchased* pane at the top of the apps list.
4. Tap the *Not On This iPod* tab near the top of the screen.
5. Tap the download from the cloud icon for the app you want to
       install.

[image: Screenshot of Updates and Purchased tab of App Store app for iPhone]